# Count for complete quantity of all order items in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, product-quantity

I have the problem that I need the complete number of shop items for a for loop.

I've already tried:

```
$total_quantity += $item->get_quantity()
$total_quantity = $order->get_item_count();
$items_count = count( $order->get_items() );
```

Unfortunately without success.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $item) {
        $total_quantity = $order->get_item_count(); <-- NOT WORKING
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $total_quantity; $i++ ) {
        $content .= '<button class="accordion">' . $item->get_name() . '</button>';
  }
}
```

The for loop in the foreach loop is supposed to cause PDF buttons to be generated. Depending on which PDF button you press, the index is transferred to JavaScript and checks which button has just been clicked.

With $ item-> get_quantity it almost worked. However, the index ($i) is reset to 0 for another product. However, it must continue. That means or if the product was put into the shopping cart 5 times and another product was only put into it once, then the button is first correctly displayed 5 times with the correct index but not for the second product.

If you have any questions about the code or need examples, please let me know and I'll update this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For order items, use `WC_Order_Item_Product` `get_quantity()` method as follow in a **`FOR`** loop:

```
$content = ''; // Initializing

// Loop through order items
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    // Loop through item quantity
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $item->get_quantity(); $i++ ) {
        $content .= '<button class="accordion">' . $item->get_name() . ' (' . $i . ')</button>';
    }
}
```

This should work now…

---

To count the complete global order items quantity you can use:

```
$total_quantity = 0; // Initializing

// Loop through order items
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $total_quantity += $item->get_quantity();
}
// Output
echo '<p>Total items quantity: '.$total_quantity.'</p>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the help yesterday. This totally worked out. But i have another problem now. Foreach order item i need the item name for the buttons. Also i need the right item name for every button i placed in my code. However, each item needs a unique class name. The goal of what I am pursuing is to download an PDF - File foreach order item. Also every order needs to be assaign to an user. Thats why i need so much help. 

If you want i can update my code or open another issue for this problem? 
I am a little overwhelmed sorry for that.